# retrieve a scalar from and xarray.DataArray

Tags: python-xarray

Indexing a specific cell in a `xarray.DataArray` returns a singleton:

```
In [3]: a = xr.DataArray(np.eye(3))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

In [4]: a                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[4]: 
<xarray.DataArray (dim_0: 3, dim_1: 3)>
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
Dimensions without coordinates: dim_0, dim_1

In [5]: a[0,0]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[5]: 
<xarray.DataArray ()>
array(1.)
```

What is the right way to access the actual scalars in a DataArray?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A reasonably clean way to do this is with [`item()`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.item.html), e.g.

```
In [4]: a[0, 0].item()
Out[4]: 1.0
```

or

```
In [5]: a.item(0, 0)
Out[5]: 1.0
```